# Como verificar se o framework esta instalado na versao correta?

Tags: c#, .net

Requisitos para instalar o software principal:
.Net Framework 4.5.1
Service Pack 1
Ou seja estou criando um gerenciador de download que baixa a versão correta do software principal(32 ou 64 bits) e o próprio gerenciador faz uma varredura na maquina do cliente atualizando se necessário os requisitos acima. Mas estou tendo dificuldades para verificar se o framework esta instalado.
Outra duvida,este software poderia ser somente executável sem que o cliente precisa-se instalar na maquina dele?

Comment: Você pode utilizar o [inno-setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). e adicionar a verificação nele, [neste](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-Installer-for-InnoSetup) tutorial tem as instruções.

Answer (score 2):

Felipe, a versão do .Net fica registrada em um chave de registro. A partir do .Net 4.5 fica registrado na chave `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full` na subchave `release`.

Você então verificar se o framework está na versão desejada usando as classes de chaves de registro, verificando se a chave existe e se a subchave está acima do valor mínimo.

Este link da Microsoft te da melhores informações sobre como identificar a versão e adquirir a versão utilizando C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Abra o prompt de comando como adm.

```
 cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64
 dir
```

vc verá as versões instaladas entre na ultima e digite msbuild -version:
exemplo:

```
 cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
 msbuild -version
```

done... vc verá a ultima versão instalada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para .net core

```
 dotnet --version
```

[image: versão .net core]